# Using $.getScript gives me an error, Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am using the following code to asynchronously, get a script for analytics tracking, I don't want it to impact performance (which it has been):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.getScript('HTTP://url.com');
</script>

</body>
```

When I use this code I get the following error in the cosole:

`Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Sounds like the issue is in the script you're loading, not $.getScript.

Comment: You're probably using an analytics script which was not designed to be loaded asynchronously (e.g. makes use of `document.write`).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yup, that sounds about right but is there a way I can prevent it hitting performance? There is a lag on other scripts due to this.

Comment: @shenku you can usually put the analytics script right before the closing `</body>`, then put your scripts right above the analytics script and do not wait for the DOM ready event -- the DOM will be ready when your scripts execute then. `window.onload` handlers are also affected by delayed scripts, so you may have to check it out as well. The only drawback with this strategy is that the analytics script starts loading later and thus has a higher risk of not registering the page view in case the user navigates to another page or closes the page too quickly.